# PHP Paypal item description

Tags: php, paypal

So i managed to get a paypal checkout working,

the problem is, whenever it gets to the paypal checkout, theres no item description: 
[image]

EDIT: i found out its not picking my database stuff anymore:

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='".$row['name']."'>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTML variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) you should `item_name`

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='".$row['Description']."' />
```

Comment: Yeah its not picking that up anymore, using 'name' tho

Answer (score 0):

So, my database tables were empty...

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer; it's the OP explaining what caused the problem.